# How to transfer a domain (securely)

Tags: domains, transfer

This might be a stupid question but I am buying a domain name from a private seller. It is an individual & not an established organization. How can I securely make the transaction so that he doesn't screw me and i get the domain & he gets the money?

Does the 3rd party charge for it? Who can do this the cheapest (and still make a secure transaction)?

Comment: Ask him who the registrar was with whom he registered the domain and then contact them via support and CC the owner and ask for the best way to securely deal with the transfer?

Answer (score 4):

I have never had to use one, but you are looking for a domain name escrow service here.  Looking at one called [Moniker](http://www.moniker.com/domainappraisalbrokerage/domainescrow.jsp), their fee is tiered based on the selling price of the domain.  I'd imagine this is a common practice with these escrow services.

Looking into how Godaddy handles these processes ([article here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1502)), I see that they use [escrow.com](http://www.escrow.com) for any domain selling for more than 1000 dollars.  I use GoDaddy for all my domain registration and management so the escrow service they use by default is a big endorsement for me, and who I would look to using first.